# How to create a Maven project from java program(Automatically)?

Tags: java, maven

Java 1.7

I want to write a program which should generate the Maven Project.

For Example:

```
public class AutoGenerate{
   public static void main(String[] args){
     // Here I will ask all the user input params like project name, location and group id and etc

   // Need to write code which should generate a dummy maven structure project.
   }
}
```

Comment: this not need just the main method, it need a big project! not easy

Comment: We want you to turn back to the  [help] and read *again* how/what to ask here. And to remember: this is not a place where you drop your vision and other people do the work for you.

Comment: check maven in 5 minutes  https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [maven archetypes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-creating-archetypes.html). Archetypes are templates for projects which you can create using `mvn archetype:generate [params]`.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse 
Configure>> Convert to Maven Project